# Aframe Strange Trigger Issue

Tags: jquery, events, triggers, aframe

edit:-> found what causes my problem https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3297 need to fix that

('I have an strange issue. I have two scenes. When i press a button you switch to the other scene and there is another button which brings you back to the first scene. I activate the button with an click on it or an gazer(fuser). Now my Problem: when i gaze on button 1 and change the scene and then click on button 2 to come back, button 1 is already triggerd (so it changes scene again). If i just gaze on buttons or just click on them everthing works fine just when i gaze something and after that click it fails. Need some help here some code:')

```
<!-----scene1------------------------------> 
  <a-entity id="browser_scene" visible="true">
    <a-entity id="scene1" visible="true">
<!--Icons-->
    <a-image id="introid" src="#introicon" position="-20 12 -13" width="9" height="9" rotation="0 75 0" transparent="true" onclick="playscene2()" event-set__enter="_event: mouseenter; color: #33ccff"
           event-set__leave="_event: mouseleave; color: #00000"></a-image>
</a-entity>

<!-----scene2-------------------------------> 
    <a-entity id="scene2" visible="false">
<!--Videosphere (intro)-->
    <a-videosphere src="#intro"></a-videosphere>                       
<!--Icons-->
    <a-image id="haus" src="#home" position="-5 -6 -1.75" width="2" height="2" rotation="35 -90 -180" transparent="true" onclick="playscene1()" event-set__enter="_event: mouseenter; color: #33ccff"
           event-set__leave="_event: mouseleave; color: #00000"></a-image>
    </a-entity>
```

```
function playscene1() {

document.getElementById('scene1').setAttribute('visible', 'true')
document.getElementById('scene2').setAttribute('visible', 'false')
document.getElementById('haus').setAttribute('visible', 'false')

var videoEl_1 = document.querySelector('#intro');

skyon()
document.querySelector('#intro').pause();
document.querySelector('#intro').currentTime = 0;

}
</script>
```

```
function playscene2() {
document.getElementById('scene1').setAttribute('visible', 'false')
document.getElementById('scene2').setAttribute('visible', 'true')
document.getElementById('haus').setAttribute('visible', 'true')

var videoEl_1 = document.querySelector('#intro'); 

document.querySelector('#intro').pause();
document.querySelector('#intro').currentTime = 0;

skyout()
videoEl_1.play();

document.getElementById('intro').addEventListener('ended',myHandler_1,false);
function myHandler_1(e) {
    if(!e) { e = window.event; }
    playscene3()
  }
}
</script>

<!--camera-->
<a-entity foo rotation="0 90 0">
  <a-camera user-height="0" look-controls>
    <a-cursor fuse="true" fusetimeout="2000"
      position="0 0 -0.1"
      geometry="primitive: ring;
      radiusInner: 0.002;
      radiusOuter: 0.003"
      material="color: red; shader: flat">
      <a-animation attribute="scale"
                      to="3 3 3"
                      dur="2000"
                      begin="cursor-fusing"
                      fill="backwards"
                      easing="linear">
      </a-animation>
   </a-cursor>
    <a-entity id="redcircle" position="0 0 -0.1" 
            geometry="primitive: ring;
            radiusInner: 0.007;
            radiusOuter: 0.0077"
            material="color: red; opacity: 0.25; shader: flat"></a-entity>
 </a-camera>  
</a-entity>
```

Comment: if somebody need some more information or if my question isnt understandable just ask :D

Comment: Please add your cursor/raycaster code so we can see the configuration. If you could post a link to a simple demo, that would also help.

Comment: the cursor is in the camera entity on the bottom part of my posted code. I try if @dirkk0 example helps me. If not i try creating a demo for better understanding.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Not sure how I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem is documented -> https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3297. workaround: if you press something move the entire scene and the camera some degrees

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a data attribute or component rather than a class, as they get automatically added/removed to/from the raycaster object list:

```
<a-cursor raycaster="objects: [data-clickable];" ... ></a-cursor>

<a-entity id="button" data-clickable ... ></a-entity>
```

Then just add and remove this with:

```
buttonEl.setAttribute('data-clickable', '');

buttonEl.removeAttribute('data-clickable');
```

Using classes, you would need to refresh the raycaster object list manually with `raycasterEl.components.raycaster.refreshObjects()`. This is not required if using the method above.

Comment: sadly it dosn´t work. I should add that this problem just happens if you press on the buttons on smartphone with your fingers the cursor works good. It seems for me that if you click something with your finger its a doubleclick

Answer (score 0):

i know use a workaround: I disable the cursor and enable it only in VR-mode. So the issue didn´t appears but another conclusion would still be better.

With that i disable my cursor (also setting visible on false):

```
document.getElementById('cursor').setAttribute('raycaster', 'objects: .notclickable');
```

Comment: I was just going to post something in this vein. I'd recommend using a data attribute or component rather than a class, though, as they get automatically added/removed to/from the raycaster object list

Answer (score 0):

It's usually harder to debug if you just show portions of your code.
But if I understand correctly you want to be able to switch through pseudo scenes with gaze fuse.

So here is a working example with pseudo scenes that hopefully help with your use case:

https://curious-electric.com/w/experiments/aframe/panorama-compass-click/

Comment: you´re right i use pseudo scenes i change the <a-sky> source and disable/enable buttons. I gonna look at the example and if i can´t fix it i try to make a demo for better understanding